# What does (@)/[some_folder] mean at the beginning of that Shell script example?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have no serious tech background, just know some Python basics. Became interested in Flask, read the Flask tutorial, saw that Flask requires setting some environment variables. Didn't know what that is, this led me to Linux and now I'm sort of addicted to that Linux Bible, I have the 9th edition. Normally man pages + Google always have answers for me. Not this time.

So there's an example backup script on p. 168, the second line right after the shebang line is:

```
 # (@)/my_backup
```

The /my_backup part does not show up anywhere in the example script again and I get that this is commented out but it bugs me that the (@) part looks like being meaningful and I can't find any information on this. Searching the bash man pages only has unrelated results and Google wasn't helpful either.

Can anyone explain to me why this line is in the example script? I understand all of the script except the reason why the 2nd line looks how it looks. Have I overlooked something important while reading the book?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in bash.

Comment: Probably just a stand-in for a complete path to the file.

Comment: and, remember, it is a comment. So it does nothing. You should not spend too much time on the reason for the comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. Will continue my Linux quest then and accept that (@) is probably just a placeholder.

Comment: Maybe you have some tool which searches this type of comment and replaces it by something meaningful. This idea is sometimes used with version control systems.